# Updating string elements in a list in Python

Tags: python, data-wrangling

I have a list of string elements where `list = [X, Y, Z]`.

I want to update the elements in the list such that it becomes `[X_AAA, X_BBB, X_CCC, Y_AAA, Y_BBB, Y_CCC, Z_AAA, Z_BBB, Z_CCC]`. Essentially, I'm appending AAA, BBB and CCC to every element in this list of strings.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Thank you!

.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like this:

```
import itertools

prefixes = ['X', 'Y', 'Z']
suffixes = ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC']
result = [f'{prefix}_{suffix}' for prefix, suffix in itertools.product(prefixes, suffixes)]
```